# Give player item once they run out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use command blocks to give a player an item (in this case cgm:advanced_bullet) every time they run out of that same item.

I've tried using this series of commands:

```
execute as @a if data entity @s {Inventory:[{id:"cgm:advanced_bullet",Count:0b}]} run tag add @s ammoRefill

give @a[tag=ammoRefill] cgm:advanced_bullet 64

tag remove @a[tag=ammoRefill] ammoRefill
```

Comment: There is no item with stack size 0. Try `execute unless` without `Count` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inventory doesn't store item stacks that don't exist, so you won't be able to find them in the player data. There is a way to do what you want with data checks, but first I'm going to show you a much better way of doing this.

Accessing block NBT or entity NBT is very slow in commands, because Minecraft has to convert the full entity / block into NBT every time you do it (and back again, if you're editing the data). If you can avoid it, your commands will cause much less lag. Fortunately, you can in this case.

#### The faster option: `clear` and `execute store`

Every command in Minecraft can return a "result" number when it's run. Not every command's result is useful, but some are very handy.

For `/clear`, the result is the number of matching items in the player's inventory. Note: it's not the number of items that were actually cleared, but the number of items that were found! So if you do `clear @s cgm:advanced_bullet 0`, the `0` will stop the command from removing any items, but the result will still be the number of `cgm:advanced_bullet`s in your inventory.

Using [the `store` subcommand of `execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#store), we can store a command's result into a score. Like so:

```
execute as @a store result score @s heldBullets run clear @s cgm:advanced_bullet 0
```

This command will give every player a score equal to the number of `cgm:advanced_bullet`s in their inventory. Just run `/scoreboard objectives add heldBullets dummy` in the chat to set up the scoreboard objective.

Your full set of commands can be:

```
execute as @a store result score @s heldBullets run clear @s cgm:advanced_bullet 0

give @a[scores={heldBullets=0}] cgm:advanced_bullet 64
```

Find how many bullets each player has, and then give them more if it's zero.

### The slower option: NBT

But to fully answer your question, this *can* be done with NBT. (It's just less efficient.) You need to check that the player *doesn't* have any stacks of `cgm:advanced_bullet`, rather than that they *do* have stacks of size zero.

```
give @a[nbt=!{Inventory:[{id:"cgm:advanced_bullet"}]}] cgm:advanced_bullet 64
```

This gives the items to any player who doesn't have a stack of bullets. But even though it's a single command, the NBT access makes it slower than the two commands above. I recommend going with the `/clear` method.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I used what you told me and turned it into a data pack using a function.